# Getting keyPressEvent in QLineEdit in Qt

Tags: qt4

I am a newbie for Qt. I am using Qt4.7 with linux os. My application is compiled to embedded mipsel device.

In my application, there is a `QWidget` containing two `pushbuttons` and a `QLineEdit`. Initially `QLineEdit` is hidden.

My requirement is: When I press a key in my application's keypad, `QlineEdit` should be shown and get entered by that key. After that it should take all the key inputs. At the same time it does not show cursor blink.

However, my application cannot show the `QlineEdit` when the key is pressed.

Also after entering keys, if I click outside of the `QLineEdit` box, it remains visible. But now also I cannot enter the keys in `QLineEdit`, i.e., after entering keys, I have to click in the outside of the `QlineEdit` to show the entered keys in `QLineEdit`.

I have tried with:

```
QLineEdit->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
```

I have a `keyPressEvent();` function. In that I try to show `QlineEdit` when the key is pressed.
But there is no improvement. Still I cannot able to solve this problem.

Can anybody give valuable advice about this problem?

Comment: I'm really not sure what is being asked here, either what you want to do or what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `keyPressEvent` on the containing `QWidget`? If so, I guess it might be eating all the key-presses before it gets to the QLineEdit

If this is the case, you could maybe use the `QWidget.keyPressEvent` to simply focus the QLineEdit if it is defocused. In psuedocode:

```
class MyContainer(QWidget):
    def keyPressEvent(event):
        if my_qlineedit.isFocused():
            # Do nothing, call default implementation, allowing
            # key-presses to be passed to QLineEdit normally
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
            return

        else:
            # Show QLineEdit (for first keystroke)
            my_qlineedit.setVisible(True)

            # Set focus for future key strokes to be sent directly to the QLineEdit
            my_qlineedit.setFocused(True)

            # Send this key-event to avoid missing a key
            my_qlineedit.keyPressedEvent(event)
```